# How to parse values from macOS extended file attributes?

Tags: macos, terminal, plist, extended-attributes

If you download a file from the internet using Safari, some extended attributes are added to the downloaded file, among which `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` which contains the original URL of the download. In Finder > <kbd>Get Info</kbd> the value of this key will be displayed under **Where from:**.

`/bin/ls -alh` shows the presence of extended attributes with a `@` in the mode column and `xattr -l filename.zip` will list all the attributes.

According to the `xattr`'s man page to print the value of an attribute one can use:

```bash
xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms filename.zip

# OUTPUT
# com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms: bplist00�_=https://example.com/filename.zip
```

So even if the content is visible, the value is in a binary format with a header of `bplist00�_`.

I tried to parse it in the following way:

```bash
xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms filename.zip > url.plist

# checking the file format:
file url.plist

# OUTPUT:
# url.plist: Apple binary property list

# assuming this should work:
plutil -convert xml1 url.plist

# OUTPUT:
# url.plist: Property List error: Unexpected character b at line 1 / JSON error: 
# JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow 
# fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.
```

Trying to parse the file with python's ootb `plistlib` throws an error too:

```py
import plistlib

with open('url.plist', 'rb') as fi:
    plist = plistlib.load(fi)

# OUTPUT:
# plistlib.InvalidFileException: Invalid file
```

From the output it looks like it is not a regular binary plist format even though `file url.plist` claims it is an '`Apple binary property list`'. Any hints as to what the format is and how to parse it to a plain text value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print it in `hex` and then run it through `xxd` like so:

```
xattr -x -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms filename.zip | xxd -r -p | plutil -p -
```

If you want to have other output format you can change `plutil` to something like:

```
plutil -convert json -o - -
```

Example output:

```
["https:\/\/another.example.com","https:\/\/example.com\/path\/"]
```

Comment: interesting approach; any hints on why `plutil covert ...` won't work? I tried all of the formats listed in the manpage, ie `xml1, binary1, json, objc,raw` and all of them fail; could it be because the value is an array of two URLs and not a single plain text value?

Comment: Hard to tell, probably the output of `xattr -p` strips some non-displayable characters. By passing `-x` you'll get raw hex output which has to be transformed into "pure" binary before passing that to `plutil`. BTW I've added a possibility to convert the output to JSON etc.

Comment: awesome! thank you! combined with `jq` a plain text string can be pulled with `/usr/bin/xattr -x -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms "$1" | xxd -r -p | plutil -convert json -o - - | jq -r '.[0]'` — this takes the first element from the array; also, I'm prefixing `xattr` because on my system there is another `xattr` in `/usr/local/bin` which doesn't understand the `-x` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using python as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33182025/191246

```py
# dependencies:
# pip install xattr biplist

import biplist
import xattr

attrs = xattr.xattr('filename.zip')

print(biplist.readPlistFromString(attrs.get('com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms')))

# OUTPUT:
# ['https://example.com/..', 'https://another.example/..']
```

With python the result is a list that can be manipulated and iterated programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Howard Oakley has created an editor for extended attributes, that may be useful for parsing the contents.

https://eclecticlight.co/xattred-sandstrip-xattr-tools/